# Is there any procedure to determine the number of layers of convolution and pooling needs in CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, pooling, conv-neural-network

When I want to use Caffe to create my own CNN, how to determine the number of convolution and pooling layer I need is suitable to extract correct features basis?

Is there any principal or documents?

Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

I am new at this too, so there may be a better answer. But I would start small, have only one hidden layer get the best accuracy out of that layer as possible then add another and see if it improves. At each stage, you are changing parameters (size of filter, learning rate, weight initialization etc.) Chapter 9 of this book: http://www.deeplearningbook.org/ might be helpful.